# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, сортировка, tkinter, словари

Написал код на python для сортировки спутников планет по нескольким критериям через tkinter, но программа не сортирует один из критериев, а именно "Период обращения в днях", присваивая одному элементу тип None. Не могу разобраться, как исправить данную проблему.

```
from tkinter import*

sput1 = {"Название": "Луна",
    "Название планеты-хозяина": "Земля",
    "Год открытия": 1969,
    "Диаметр в км": 3474,
    "Период обращения в днях": 27}

sput2 = {"Название": "Деймос",
    "Название планеты-хозяина": "Марс",
    "Год открытия": 1877,
    "Диаметр в км": 807,
    "Период обращения в днях": 1}

sput3 = {"Название": "Ио",
    "Название планеты-хозяина": "Юпитер",
    "Год открытия": 1610,
    "Диаметр в км": 3642,
    'Период обращения в днях': 15}
sput4 = {"Название": 'Титан',
    "Название планеты-хозяина": "Сатурн",
    "Год открытия": 1655,
    "Диаметр в км": 5152,
    "Период обращения в днях": 16}

sput5 = {"Название": "Оберон",
    "Название планеты-хозяина": "Уран",
    "Год открытия": 1787,
    "Диаметр в км": 1522,
    "Период обращения в  днях": 10}

list2 = (sput1, sput2, sput3, sput4, sput5)


def exit_programm():
   root.destroy()


def insertion_sort(num):
   global index
   w = num.widget
   index = int(w.curselection()[0])
def Clear():
   text.delete('1.0', END)
def method_name(item_to_insert):
   assert isinstance(item_to_insert, object)
def Num(planet):
   global list_for_sort
   list_for_sort = []
   Clear()
   for k in range(len(list2)):
      list_for_sort.append(list2[k].get(planet))
   i=0
   for i in range(1, len(list_for_sort)):
      item_to_insert = list_for_sort[i]
      j=i-1 
      method_name(item_to_insert)
      while j>=0 and list_for_sort[j] > item_to_insert:
         list_for_sort[j+1]=list_for_sort[j]
         j -= 1
      list_for_sort[j+1] = item_to_insert
   print(list_for_sort)
   list_for_sort.reverse()
   i = 0
   l = i
   c = len(list2)
   while True:
      if list_for_sort[i] == list2[l].get(planet):
         text.insert(1.0, 'Спутник № ' + str(c) + '\n')
         for key in list2[l]:
            text.insert(2.0, str(key) + ' -> ' + str(list2[l][key]) + '\n')
         text.insert(1.0, '\n')

         c -= 1
         l = 0
         list_for_sort.pop(i)

      else:
         l += 1
      if len(list_for_sort) == 0:
         break
def set_index():
    try:
        if index == 1:
            Num('Название планеты-хозяина')
        elif index == 2:
            Num('Год открытия')
        elif index == 3:
            Num('Диаметр в км')
        elif index == 4:
            Num('Период обращения в днях')
        elif index == 0:
            Num('Название')
    except NameError:
       Clear()
       text.insert(1.0, 'Сначала выберите, что сортировать')

root = Tk()
root.title('Сортировка')
root.configure(background='gainsboro')
listbox1 = Listbox(root, font='Times 16', height=5, width=20, selectmode=SINGLE)
listbox1.grid(row=0, column=0)
list1 = [u"Название", u"Название планеты-хозяина",
     u"Год открытия", u"Диаметр в км", u"Период обращения в днях"]
for i in list1:
   listbox1.insert(END, i)
listbox1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', insertion_sort)

text = Text(root, font='Times 16', height=15, width=40)
text.grid(row=0, column=1)
i = 0
c = len(list2)
while i < len(list2):
   text.insert(1.0, 'Спутник № ' + str(c) + '\n')
   for key in list2[i]:
      text.insert(2.0, str(key) + ' -> ' + str(list2[i][key]) + '\n')
   i += 1
   text.insert(1.0, '\n')
   c -= 1
bt1 = Button(root, text='Отсортировать\n вставками', fg='white', command=set_index,
         background='green', font=("Comic Sans MS", 15, 'bold'), width=20)
bt1.grid(row=3, column=0)
bt3 = Button(root, text='Выход', fg='white', command=exit_programm,
         background='red', font=("Comic Sans MS", 15, 'bold'), width=20)
bt3.grid(row=3, column=1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: отформатируйте пожалуйста свой пример.

Comment: Приведите минимальный исполняемый пример. Ваш код ничего не выводит

Comment: мой ответ вам помог или нет?

Comment: @Danis да, спасибо

Comment: @СергейГагарин тогда примите мой ответ (галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас в `sput5` в `Период обращения в днях` после буквы `в` стоит лишний пробел. поэтому метод `get` возвращает `None`

вот как должен выглядить `sput5`:

```
sput5 = {"Название": "Оберон",
    "Название планеты-хозяина": "Уран",
    "Год открытия": 1787,
    "Диаметр в км": 1522,
    "Период обращения в днях": 10}
```